# Name validation problem - page does not use the updated inputs

Tags: php, jquery

I made a registration form.
inside it I added a jQuery function responsible for the validation of the username (not too short and not already in use) and it seems to work properly but the page does not keep checking if the username inserted by the user has been modified to match the set standards.
it only check for the username as the page load (it displays immidiately "username too short") and then no more checking.

```
<form class="register_form_container" action="register.php" method="post">
  <div class="inputs_box">
    <p class="input_register_title">Name</p><input type="text" name="nome" value="">
    <p class="input_register_title">Age</p><input type="text" name="eta" value="">
    <p class="input_register_title">City</p><input type="text" name="citta" value="">
    <p class="input_register_title">Country</p><input type="text" name="paese" value="">
    <p class="input_register_title">Mail</p><input type="text" name="mail" value="">
    <p class="input_register_title">Password</p><input type="text" name="password" value="">
    <p class="input_register_title">Psychonaut name</p><input id="username_input" style="font-size:2vw;" type="text" name="username" value="">
  <div id="feedback">
  </div>
  <div class="input_register_title">
    <input class="submit_register_btn" type="submit" name="registra_user" value="ENTER THE COMMUNITY">
  </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jQuery.js"></script> -->
<script type = "text/javascript">

    // when the document is ready, run the jquery script
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#feedback').load('check.php').show();

        /* We use keyup so that everytime the user type in the keyboard, it'll check the database and get results however,
          you can change this to a button click which is I think, more advisable.
          Sometimes, your server response is slow but just for this demo, we'll use 'keyup' */
        $('#username_input').keyup(function(){

            $.post('check.php', { username: form.username.value },
                function(result){
                    $('#feedback').html(result).show();
                });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see an error in the developer tools console.
I think your problem here is that form.username.value does not exist.
Try this:

```
        $('#username_input').keyup(function(){

            $.post('check.php', { username: $(this).val() },
                function(result){
                    $('#feedback').html(result).show();
                });

        });
```